# Create jar including classes and jar files

Tags: java, classpath, mysql-connector

I have my program **deduction.java** . I compiled it successfully.
I used **mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar** file at compile time. Now I want to make single jar file which should have **deduction.java** and **mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar** classes.

I used this command

```
jar -cvfe deduction.jar *.class
```

but I am not able to include mysql-connector classes. Please help to solve this.

Comment: is your mysql-connector-java jar inside your buildpath ?

Comment: mysql-connector.jar and  deduction.jar are in same directory and I want to make single jar for all these classes.

Comment: Have you seen ? [JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a folder, unpack mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar in it, add deduction.java and run

```
jar cvf deduction.jar *
```

inside this folder. Or copy mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar as deduction.jar then add deduction.java to it

```
jar uvf deduction.jar deduction.java
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you should not try to regroup your dependencies into a single .jar, but instead provide them separately.  I guess your application is a command-line executable?  You have many options:

- For example, you can group them in a folder

your-app/

```
    /app.sh

    /deduction.jar

    /mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
```

And your app.sh would look like

```
java -cp deduction.jar;mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar deduction
```

Assuming the class deduction contains your main() method

Comment: good one +1 I usually don't bother myself in building it with eclipse :)